# Obtener datos anteriores para mostrar en vista Editar. Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un CRUD y lo que quiero es que al momento de editar la información en la vista Editar los datos seleccionados ya estén cargados. Aparece el formulario pero en blanco sin nada ya cargado. Actualmente lo tengo así

```
Route::resource('/promociones','PromocionesController'); //RUTA

    public function edit($id) //CONTROLADOR
{
    $promocion = Promocion::find($id);
    $sucursales=Almacen::where('ESTADO','1')->pluck('NOMBRE','CODIGO');
    return view('admin.marquee.editar', compact('promocion','sucursales'));
}



public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
      //Actualizar la informacion
        $promocion = Promocion::find($id);
        $promocion->INFORMACION = $request->get("info");
        $promocion->ALMACEN = $request->get("almacen");
        $promocion->save();


        return redirect()->route('promociones.index');
}
```

-------------VISTA--------------------------

```
 {!! Form::model($promocion, ['route' => ['promociones.update', $promocion->CODIGO],'method'=>'PATCH']) !!}
        <div >
                    {!! Form::textarea('info', null, array(
                        'rows'=>'3',
                        'class'=>'form-control',
                        'required'=>'required'
                        )) 
                    !!}
              </div>
              <div>
                <select name="almacen" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
                    @foreach ($sucursales as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>  
                    @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>

    <br>
    {!! Form::submit('Guardar', array('class'=>'btn btn-success'))!!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Como se llaman los atributos de tu modelo `Promocion`? Podrías hacer un `dd($promocion)` y mostrarlo?

Comment: Se muestran asi:   #attributes: array:3 [
    "CODIGO" => 1
    "INFORMACION" => "a"
    "ALMACEN" => 1
  ]

Comment: El le tienes que poner al input, el mismo nombre que el del atributo. Ej `{!! Form::textarea('INFORMACION', null) !!}`

Comment: Gracias!, el input text trae el dato pero el select no, no es de la misma manera?

Comment: Es que no estás usando [LaravelCollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.8/html#drop-down-lists) en el select. Podés probar algo así
`{!! Form::select('ALMACEN', $sucursales, null) !!}`, también que coincida el nombre y pasándole el array de opciones como segundo parámetro.

Comment: Listo, GRACIAS! c: